# Is it possible to completely control your Tor circuit?

Tags: circuit

I'm pretty new to the community. A "Tor" circuit usually consists of an entry guard, a middle node and an exit.

I know that it's possible to change the entry guard manually, but can you also change every part of the connection manually?

I really don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Tor control protocol you can create the streams by hand. I suggest using Stem library to speed the things up - but it's basically a Telnet one, so you can even write your own wrappers for your particular task(I'm doing it myself - it's harder and slower, but as for me it's worth it's efforts applied).